# UIButton in a custom UIView sub class not triggering action events

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, action, selector

This has been asked multiple times and I am sorry for that.But I want to get a good deep understanding why it does this. So here is the thing:

**ViewController** -> **customView** -> **UIButton** 
I am trying to access the button in view controller using delegate/protocols. But before doing all that I want to first make sure that the button triggers the selector methods.

In customView class I have two UIButtons, added targets to them:

```
   var photoButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("Photos", for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleAddPhotoButton), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()
```

Then in handlePhotoButton (still in custom class) I am saying this:

```
    @objc func handleAddPhotoButton() {
    print("button")
}
```

However, it just doesn't work. The constraints are fine. I have checked the heirarchy debugger as well, and the button is on top. In view controller the custom view is initialized like this:

```
    lazy var accessoryView: AccessoryView = {
    let view = AccessoryView()
    view.delegate = self
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()
```

My guess is that the view is not being hold on to by self. But what is going wrong here. Please help!

Comment: Try add lazy to button as well

Comment: It worked. Swift -_-

Comment: Thanks a lot tho!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the 'lazy' right before the declaration of your button